# Expanding a node of a JTree minimizes GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jtree, rsyntaxtextarea

I have created a simple Swing application which currently consists of a JToolBar, a JTree and a [RSyntaxTextArea](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea), all inside a GridBagLayout.

The JTree has currently only one top node and that has only one child node.
[image: Complete UI with JToolBar, JTree and RSyntaxTextArea]
*Complete UI with JToolBar, JTree and RSyntaxTextArea*

When expanding the top node of the JTree, the whole GridBagLayout kind of "minimizes":
[image: The UI after expanding the top node of the JTree.]

I've googled this phenominum, but since there's no error message or something else in the console, I'm kind of helpless right now.

I'm using the following code to create the UI:

```
RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea(50, 150);
textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_JAVA);
textArea.setCodeFoldingEnabled(true);
RTextScrollPane sp = new RTextScrollPane(textArea);

cp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
cp.add(createToolbar(), c);

c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 1;
c.ipadx = 90;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
cp.add(createTree(), c);

c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 1;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
cp.add(sp, c);

...

private JToolBar createToolbar() {
    JToolBar tb = new JToolBar("Toolbar", JToolBar.HORIZONTAL);

    JButton ob = new JButton(new ImageIcon("..."));

    tb.add(ob);

    tb.setFloatable(false);
    tb.setRollover(true);

    return tb;
}

...

private JTree createTree() {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Projects");
    JTree tree = new JTree(top);

    DefaultMutableTreeNode test = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("I'm a test!");
    top.add(test);

    return tree;
}
```

***Update***: A minimal code example to compile on your system for testing purposes:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Tester extends JFrame {

    public Tester () {
        initializeComponent();
    }

    private void initializeComponent() {
        JPanel cp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(50, 150);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        cp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        cp.add(createToolbar(), c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.ipadx = 90;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        cp.add(createTree(), c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        cp.add(sp, c);
        setContentPane(cp);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private JTree createTree() {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Projects");
        JTree tree = new JTree(top);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode test = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("I'm a test!");
        top.add(test);
        return tree;
    }

    private JToolBar createToolbar() {
        JToolBar tb = new JToolBar("Toolbar", JToolBar.HORIZONTAL);
        JButton ob = new JButton("Button");
        tb.add(ob);
        tb.setFloatable(false);
        tb.setRollover(true);
        return tb;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Tester().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Please consider creating and posting in your question a valid [mcve] a ***small*** program that we can compile, run, and that demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sure, updated my question.

Comment: (1-) @AlexanderLeithner,  The code you posted is NOT an `MCVE` since we don't have access to the custom classes. In any case you already have your answer. Time to do some reading.

Comment: @camickr Oh, thank you, overlooked them... Will replace them by simple JTextAreas right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > When expanding the top node of the JTree, the whole GridBagLayout kind of "minimizes":

The GridBagLayout will shrink to the minimum size of a component when there is not enough space to display the entire component.

> Swing application which currently consists of a JToolBar, a JTree and a RSyntaxTextArea, all inside a GridBagLayout.

I would just use the default `BorderLayout` of the frame:

```
add(toolbar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
add(treeScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(textAreaScrollPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Note how I added the JTree to a JScrollPane. Now scrollbars will appear for the tree when needed.

If you really want to use the `GridBagLayout` then read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for an explanation of how to use the various constraints. You may want to start with the "weightx/y" constraints which control which components get space as the frame size is changed. Also, look at the "fill" constraint.

Comment: That would append the RSyntaxTextArea to the end of the dialog, right? That's not how I want it to be displayed, just next to the JTree on its right. But good to know about the shrinking (but I really do not know why there should not be enough space)...

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner, `I want it to be displayed, just next to the JTree on its right` - so then use a different BorderLayout constraint to put the text area on the right. Read the tutorial. I provided a link to the GridBagLayout. You will also find a section on the BorderLayout.

Comment: Thank you, overlooked `weightx/y` (but had read this tutorial before)...